# What's one transaction in Azure table?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm trying to figure out the cost for the Azure cloud storage service. It say it only cost $0.01 per 100 000 transaction. This one transaction is for read and write I guess. However when doing query with LINQ. For instance if I would update a value found in 100 entities. Would this invoke one transaction, assuming I can do a batch update?

For example with this following code, it would count as one transaction will it?

```
CloudTableQuery<Data> aBatch = (from e in s_context.CreateQuery<Data>("Table") where e.PartitionKey == "some_pkey" select e).AsTableServiceQuery<Data>();
foreach (Data d in aBatch)
{
   d.Content = "updated content";
   s_context.UpdateObject(d);
}
s_context.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code looks wrong... you'd need the `UpdateObject` call to be in the loop.

But to answer your general question, one batch update is one transaction. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx for a pretty detailed explanation.

Comment: I think the code's still wrong. Should be `s_context.UpdateObject(d)` in the loop. :-)